# .Net - WPF .Net Core 3.1 - CapturePicker The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core-3.1

Currently I'm trying to develop a solution uses **.Net Core 3.1** and it's responsible to select multiple capture windows, to be shared when focused.

I've made it work using a list, but I think would be much more elegant and user friendly if I've a picker that shows a preview of the window before selecting.

I'm trying to use **GraphicsCapturePicker** but I'm getting the following error:

`The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread`
[image]

Here is the following methods that I'm using to open the picker:

```cs
public async void OpenCapturePicker(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("OpenCapturePicker");
    await Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(OpenCapturePicker);

}
private async void OpenCapturePicker()
{
    var picker = new GraphicsCapturePicker();

    picker.SetWindow(_capturableWindowHandle);
    var item = await picker.PickSingleItemAsync();
    if (item == null) return;
    //rest of code
}
```

The **_capturableWindowHandle** is defined in the constructor of the class like:

```cs
public SomeClass(){
 _capturableWindowHandle = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
}
```

Also I've an extension class that allows me to use the **SetWindow** method

```cs
public  static class CaptureHelper
{
    static readonly Guid GraphicsCaptureItemGuid = new Guid("79C3F95B-31F7-4EC2-A464-632EF5D30760");
    public static GraphicsCaptureItem CreateItemForWindow(IntPtr windowInteropHandler)
    {
        var factory = WindowsRuntimeMarshal.GetActivationFactory(typeof(GraphicsCaptureItem));
        var interop = (IGraphicsCaptureItemInterop) factory;
        var itemPointer = interop.CreateForWindow(windowInteropHandler, GraphicsCaptureItemGuid);
        var item = Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(itemPointer) as GraphicsCaptureItem;
        Marshal.Release(itemPointer);

        return item;
    }
    public static void SetWindow(this GraphicsCapturePicker picker, IntPtr hwnd)
    {
        var interop = (IInitializeWithWindow)(object)picker;
        interop.Initialize(hwnd);
    }
}
```

## **Update**

Here is the [link](https://github.com/codescovery/capture-manager/tree/feature/previewSelectWindow) of the branch that I'm using to add this feature

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it an UWP app?

Comment: It's a wpf application. I've just updated the question title to make it more clear

Comment: .net6+ required, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/develop/ui-input/display-ui-objects#for-classes-that-implement-iinitializewithwindow

Comment: Does this have to be asynchronous? Also as a general rule, you shouldn't have your async methods return void. Maybe swap that out for a Task instead?

Comment: I saw an example that showed me to use this way

Comment: @HansPassant are they the same thing?

Comment: @GrantByrne Check the accepted answer in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/178213/graphicscapturepicker-doesnt-work-in-wpf-net-5-pro).

Comment: Not that it'll help here so much but you should not put anything that can error in a constructor. If it errors you have nothing.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using exactly? You should provided a complete reproducible and compilable sample project somewhere, it would be easier to analyze.

Comment: I've just updated the post with the git public repo. And added more details regarding it

Comment: This works fine for me in your project: https://gist.github.com/smourier/46c65ffa0db45a4122dae6c82909aaa1 PS: make sure you have IInitializeWithWindow properly defined, it can be found on the web with a wrong IID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

This Code worked for me:

```
    if (!GraphicsCaptureSession.IsSupported()) {
        Trace.WriteLine("No Capture Support");
        return;
    }

    // var picker = new GraphicsCapturePicker();
    // picker.SetWindow(_capturableWindowHandle);
    // var item = await picker.PickSingleItemAsync();

    var interopWindow = new WindowInteropHelper(this);
    var hwnd = interopWindow.Handle;
    var picker = new GraphicsCapturePicker();
    picker.SetWindow(hwnd);
    var item = await picker.PickSingleItemAsync();
    if (item == null) {
        return;
    }

    _windowCaptureService.StartCapture(item, _capturableWindowHandle);
```

Be aware: This code is not doing anything if you put a breakpoint in it... Maybe it is initialized with the debugger window in this case...??? But without breakpoints it is working on my Windows 10 machine.

**First Answer:**

The error message is telling you, that something was created on a different thread than it is used later on. I don't see your complete code here, but you should check, if you e.g. call the constructor of SomeClass in the same thread as

```
picker.SetWindow(_capturableWindowHandle);
```

Same thing with all other code involved here or prior to OpenCapturePicker...

Comment: I can share My whole code If needed, but as I Said, in the constructor of the class that invokes the capture Picker I get it's handle than passa It to the SetWindow method.

Comment: I've just updated the post with more details and with the public repo link

Comment: I looked at your code and updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the main problem was that the way I was setting the window handle.